# T4 non starting problem

Tags: starting, vw, euro-van

I have a VW T4. It periodically does not start. It will start and drive fine for about a month. Then for about 20 minutes it wont start at all. All the lights come on but the engine will appear dead. The starter wont even turn over and there in not even a click. It is absolutely dead.

After about 20 minutes it starts fire again and for the next month it drives fine.

I have had the battery checked and it is fine. I don't know if this is a engine problem or an immobilizer problem.

Comment: Definitely not an engine problem, if the starter motor does nothing and you don't hear even a click. Failure symptoms also don't indicate battery as the cause. Immobilizer problem? Could be, but does your VW T4 have an immobilizer?

Comment: Immobiliser would be my first thought as well - what year is the T4?